# What was the need of all those magical tricks such as the rabbit trick or the bubble trick etc. on the second act in Now You See Me?

Tags: now-you-see-me

In the second show, the one in New Orleans, of *Now You See Me* before the Four Horsemen reveal that they had given away the money of Arther Tressler to the victims of Katrina, the Four Horsemen did some magic tricks.

These were the rabbit trick, the bubble trick etc. and they said that the tricks were connected.

But how were those tricks connected or what was the purpose of those tricks?

Answer (score 4):

Essentially there were four tricks shown..

The rabbit trick, the bubble trick, the card throwing and the hypnotism.

Now these aren't connected to each other *but* they are connected to things that happen later on in the movie. They are clues and foreshadowing of things to come.

**We** are the ones being told that they are **connected to later events we will see in the movie**...not the theatre audience.

**The Rabbit Trick**

The trick here isn't the rabbit...it's the mirror box used to hide the rabbit inside the box.

A much larger version of this box is used to hide the giant vault in the warehouse.

[image]

[image]

**The Bubble Trick**

This is about *invisible wires* which the Horsemen use to escape from the theatre a few minutes later.

[image]

**The Card Throwing**

Having demonstrated his dexterity in the magic act, Jack Wilder again uses card throwing as part of his 'escape' from the FBI as they storm the apartment building later.

[image]

**Hypnosis**

This is used a couple of times in the movie, firstly to create the 'football team' of audience members to sack the 'quarterback' FBI agent and again later to hypnotise another FBI agent into authorising the supposed moving of the vault.